# Get the commit hash of the latest successful workflow run from within the current workflow run in GitHub Actions?

Tags: git, github-actions

I'm writing a LaTeX document in a GitHub repository and I want to use [git-latexdiff](https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff) to compile a pdf file which shows the differences between `HEAD` and the commit hash of the last successful workflow run:

`git latexdiff "$LAST_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT_HASH" HEAD --no-view -o diff.pdf`

So I need a way to access the commit hash of the latest successful workflow run from within the current workflow run.

I didn't find anything in the docs but maybe there is a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually solved the problem myself by writing a small GitHub Action using the [GitHub Actions API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/):

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

try {
  const octokit = github.getOctokit(core.getInput('github_token'));

  octokit.actions.listWorkflowRuns({
    owner: process.env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY.split('/')[0],
    repo: process.env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY.split('/')[1],
    workflow_id: core.getInput('workflow_id'),
    status: "success",
    branch: core.getInput('branch'),
    event: "push"
  }).then( res => {
    const headCommits = res.data.workflow_runs.map(run => {return run.head_commit});

    const sortedHeadCommits = headCommits.sort( (a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(a.timestamp);
        const dateB = new Date(b.timestamp);
        if (dateA < dateB) return -1;
        if (dateA > dateB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    const lastSuccessCommitHash = sortedHeadCommits[sortedHeadCommits.length -1].id;

    core.setOutput("commit_hash", lastSuccessCommitHash)
  })
} catch (error) {
  core.setFailed(error.message);
}
```

Comment: This is just a fun and unimportant nit-pick, but for the sort function you can just do `.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)` and it has the same effect :D.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Powershell

```console
$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs"
$token = "********"
$response = invoke-restMethod $url  -headers @{Authorization = "bearer $token"}


$response.workflow_runs | ForEach-Object {
  if($_.conclusion -eq "success"){
    $last_successful_commit = $_.head_sha
    break
  }
} 
Write-host "Last successful commit is $last_successful_commit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of `index.js` for my custom `last-successful-commit-action` GitHub Action based on [skyfrk's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62378683/4343618). I had to update the syntax for interacting with octokit since it seems like the APIs have changed since their answer was originally published.

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

try {
    // Get inputs
    const token = core.getInput("github-token");
    const workflowId = core.getInput("workflow-id");
    const branch = core.getInput("branch");    
    const debug = core.getInput("debug") === 'true'; // Convert input to boolean

    // Validate inputs
    if (!token) {
        core.setFailed("Input 'github-token' is required.");
        return;
    }
    if (!workflowId) {
        core.setFailed("Input 'workflow-id' is required.");
        return;
    }
    if (!branch) {
        core.setFailed("Input 'branch' is required.");
        return;
    }
    if (debug) {
        console.log(`Debug mode is enabled. Inputs: github-token=***, workflow-id=${workflowId}, branch=${branch}`);
    }

    const octokit = github.getOctokit(token);
    const owner = process.env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY.split("/")[0];
    const repo = process.env.GITHUB_REPOSITORY.split("/")[1];

    octokit.rest.actions.listWorkflowRuns({
        owner: owner,
        repo: repo,
        workflow_id: workflowId,
        status: "success",
        branch: branch
    })
    .then(res => {
        const workflowRuns = res.data.workflow_runs;
        if (debug) {
            console.log("workflowRuns:", JSON.stringify(workflowRuns, null, 2));
        }

        if (workflowRuns.length < 1) {
            core.setFailed("No workflow runs found. Make sure the workflow has completed successfully at least once.");
            return;
        }

        const headCommits = workflowRuns.map(run => { return run.head_commit });
        if (debug) {
            console.log("headCommits:", JSON.stringify(headCommits, null, 2));
        }

        const sortedHeadCommits = headCommits.sort((a, b) => {
            const dateA = new Date(a.timestamp);
            const dateB = new Date(b.timestamp);
            if (dateA < dateB) return -1;
            if (dateA > dateB) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        if (debug) {
            console.log("sortedHeadCommits:", JSON.stringify(sortedHeadCommits, null, 2));
        }

        const lastSuccessCommitHash = sortedHeadCommits[sortedHeadCommits.length - 1].id;
        if (debug) {
            console.log("lastSuccessCommitHash:", JSON.stringify(lastSuccessCommitHash, null, 2));
        }

        core.setOutput("commit-hash", lastSuccessCommitHash);
    });
} catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
}
```